# Having trouble inserting .dat using array and sorting

Tags: c++, arrays

Good day

I am having trouble with importing a `.dat` file. I need to use an array function to get the values in the `.dat` file in ascending order.

Below is what I have so far and I have checked sites like [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/229239-question-store-dat-file-into-array-really-confused/) for assistance, but with no luck.

The `.dat` file has the following numbers which should be sorted in ascending order:

```
63 2 23 89 150 890 250 12 36 15 70 62 89 21 20 45 56 26 87 63
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

//swap function
void sortAscending(int type[], int size)
{
    int Max = 0;

    for (int j = Max; j < (size -1); j++)
    {
        for (int i = Max; i < (size -1); i++)
        {
            if (type[i] > type[i+1])
            {
                int temp = type[i];
                type[i] = type[i +1];
                type[i+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    //Display swapped values
    for (int j = Max; j < (size -1); j++)
        cout << type[j] << " ";

    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream in_stream; //Assign to in_stream

    int filename[20]; //array assigned to 20

    in_stream.open("Numbers.dat"); //Open .dat file

    sortAscending(filename, 20); //call function

    //Check if file failed to load
    if (in_stream.fail())
    {
          cout << "Output file opening failed.\n";
          exit(1);
    }

    in_stream >> filename[20]; //write to in_stream

    in_stream.close();

    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: What's your problem? 'I'm having trouble' isn't enough.

Comment: You should also tag this with the language you're using.

Comment: Should be sorted now.

Answer (score -1):

Merely opening a file wont read it automatically and fill your array. Where are you reading the values from the .dat file to the array?

1. First read all values and populate the array.
2. Sort the array.
3. Write data back to the file.